# How does this strange python decorator work

Tags: python, decorator

I was looking through the source for the pyFacebook library and found the following code:

```
def require_login(next=None, internal=None, required_permissions=None):
    def decorator(view):
        def newview(request, *args, **kwargs):
            next = newview.next
            internal = newview.internal

            try:
                fb = request.facebook
            except:
                raise ImproperlyConfigured('Make sure you have the Facebook middleware installed.')

            if internal is None:
                internal = request.facebook.internal

...           

            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
        newview.next = next
        newview.internal = internal
        return newview
    return decorator
```

I have tried to skip irrelelvant code, hence the ellipsis in the middle. The full listing can be found at https://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/blob/master/facebook/djangofb/__init__.py

My confusion stems from the reference on the fourth line to the 'next' attribute of the nested function. I can't figure out what the value of `newview.next` should be, whenever I try similar experiments myself I get 'function has no attribute internal' errors. However, the code works as I am using it in a django project without problems. Would be very happy if someone could explain to me what is happening here.

Comment: I've edited my answer - now it shows you exactly the same situation as you see in th pyFacebook in a demo code.

Comment: Note: do not do what the programmer of this snippet did, rename `next`.  `next` is a builtin function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python a variable defined inside a function is not the same as defined outside as a property of a function.

The following example will probably help:

```
cass A:
  a = 1
  def `__init__`(self):
    self.a = 2

print A().a
print A.a
```

UPD:
The object *newview* is in the scope inside the function is due to the definition just after the function:

```
newview.next = next
```

Remember, in Python functions are also objects and can also have attributes!

Here is a more helpfull example:

```
def b():
  x=b.x
  print x

b()
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "<stdin>", line 2, in b
>   AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'x'
b.x = 1
b()
> 1
```

There is no magic here: *b()* does not know it's name. It just sees a variable *b* in it's scope that points to itself. It could be some variable *d* defined by

```
d = b
d.x = 1
```

Comment: So is this a closure? If not then what's the difference?

Comment: @spade78 Yes, it is. Both _decorator_ and _newview_ are not seen from outside and uses their local scope variales only. So, they are closures. I'm not a theoretician. Look at [Wikipedia definition of closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)#Python).

Comment: Ok, I think I see it. *newview* is an object defined as a method that is enclosed in the scope of *decorator* which creates the **closure**. *decorator* in turn is enclosed in the scope of *require_login* creating another closure. Then while in the scope of *decorator* the *newview* object's properties are bound with objects passed in from the *require_login* method call so that when the *newview* object is invoked some time later, it has bound properties to work with already. @alex-jg: hope this adds to poltos explanation.

Comment: Aha! I get it now. Thanks for your explanations, this little snippet has been bothering me for a while.